# loading program in econotag (contiki 2.7)

Tags: c, makefile, contiki

I am currently trying to run my code(written and compiled in contiki 2.7)  in econotag. However i wasn't able to do so. I can compile with out any problem using

```
make TARGET=econotag hello-world.
```

but when i try to upload using the command

```
make TARGET=econotag hello-world.upload
```

the following message appears

```
../../platform/econotag/Makefile.econotag:10: ../..
make: *** No rule to make target `hello-world.upload'.  Stop.
```

I know it used to work perfectly in contiki-2.6 with TARGET=redbee-econotag. so i tried it but the message was

```
**** This platform is old and will soon be removed **** 

 please use TARGET=econotag instead.

 (or set ALLOW_OLD_PLATFORMS=1 to proceed)

 .  Stop.
```

I have seen some posts about installing the tool chain for uploading on econotag. but they didn't provide step by step procedure.
can anyone tell me what/how i should to install the tool chain to solve this problem and what command i should use after installation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how my colleague solved it

first compile the program you want to load (in this case hello-world) with
    the command

> `make TARGET=econotag hello-world`

note that this will generate a binary file with file name hello-world_econotag.bin (in the same directory with the code)

then go to directory

`contiki-2.7/cpu/mc1322x/tools`

and execute the pearl script used to upload binary files. (use the following command)

```
 sudo ./mc1322x-load.pl  -f "path to your binary file" -t /dev/ttyUSB1
```

this will upload the binary of your code to the econotag.
then reset your device (either with command or manually)
and the code should be running now